# Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I need a simple example program to send and receive a message through NSNotificationCenter in Swift? 
Im using core audio and I need to notify my app if the head phones are removed while I am playing audio. I don't know if I should add the observer in the app delegate or in my view since I have to keep playing audio in background.

This is the function that I use to control the route change to know if the headphones are removed.

```
-(void)handleRouteChange:(NSNotification *)notif
{
   NSDictionary *dict = notif.userInfo;
   AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *routeDesc = dict[AVAudioSessionRouteChangePreviousRouteKey];
   AVAudioSessionPortDescription *prevPort = [routeDesc.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
   if ([prevPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones]) {
        //Head phone removed
      }
 }
```

Comment: for swift 2.0 and swift 3.0 check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315228/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a notification

```
let thisNotification = NSNotification(name: "createdNotification", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(thisNotification)
```

To observe for notifications

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"onCreatedNotification", name:"createdNotification", object: nil)
func onCreatedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("Notification received")
}
```

Comment: Thanks this help me to figure out, the only correption is that when you add an observer the name is an string.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleRouteChange:", name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil);
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: A tiny bit of explanation of code only answers most often makes the answer more more helpful.